# Stop work if all threads are idle

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some number of consumer threads, any of which can also act as producer. How should I know when they all have finished their work?

```
class Worker extends Thread{
    void process(Task t){
        ...
        if(needsMoreWork(t)){
            queue.addAll(extractTasks(t));
        }
    }
    public void run(){
        while(isRunning){
            Task t = queue.take();//I need to finish somehow.
            process(t);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using `Thread`s manually, submit your tasks to an `ExecutorService`, and use a `CountDownLatch`, `CyclicBarrier`, or `Phaser` to synchronize them, depending on whether you need multiple cycles of your job and whether you have the same number of task components in each cycle.

Depending on what specifically your `process` consists of, a `ForkJoinPool` might be an option to consider; it basically wraps up the idea of "perform this same operation on a bunch of items and collect the results".

Comment: Actually I'm trying to implement parallel tree traversal.

Comment: @guest-414 Then depending on what you're doing while you traverse that tree, `ForkJoinPool` could be exactly what you want. It's helpful when you have a map/reduce situation, and so if your traversal produces some summary function over the tree, a recursive fork/join would handle all the concurrency for you.